# Copy class but overwrite the existing class imports

Tags: java, import

I have a class with an existing import:

```
import org.packageA.Peeler

public class Potato {

    Peeler peeler = new Peeler();

}
```

I'd like to be able to copy this class or create an object with it but change "import org.packageA.Peeler" to "import org.packZ.Peeler".

Is this possible to do dynamically?

Comment: What is your idea behind that? What do you want to do?

Comment: I have a Selenium testing environment.   I want to be able to run all the testing methods under different parameters that are set within their imports.   The way the testing methods in these classes are written the only alternative to changing the imports that I can see is duplicating dozens of class files and then hardcoding the altered imports.  Maybe there's another alternative.

Answer (score 1):

No.

import statements are a bit of a misnomer. `import com.foo.A;` means: **Anytime I write just `A` in this source file, imagine I wrote `com.foo.A`** and that is *all it means*. It does not mean: Initialize this class or parse this source file or any other such thing (which is usually what `import` means in other environments).

Thus, what you're asking is: Can I take `class Potato { org.packA.Peeler peeler = new org.packA.Peeler(); }` and somehow dynamically create a different Potato class that is as if I wrote `class Potato { org.packA.Peeler peeler = new org.packA.Peeler(); }` - to which the answer is no; `org.packA.Peeler` is as related to `org.packZ.Peeler` as guns and grandmas (i.e.: That they have the same name is immaterial).

Even if you could, what would that mean? Java is statically and nominally typed, it wouldn't be possible to write code that refers to this rewritten potato class without using reflection or dynamic code generation which, in java at any rate, are almost always the wrong answer.

Some exotic options you do have:

1. Use a regexp or build script plugin to make a source file with some renames applied and include it in the build and compilation process (bad idea, but I guess you can do that)
2. Use ASM, BCEL or some other classfile tool to create a new class file in byte array form with renames applied, have a custom classloader that dynamically loads this, and then generate bytecode that uses this, or use reflective access. This is extremely convoluted, requires a ton of code, and is almost useless.

Perhaps take a step back and explain the problem you have that made you think: I know! I'll dynamically rewrite this class to use a different package! But I don't know how so I'll ask SO - except you're asking the wrong question, ask about your original problem.

Comment: I have a Selenium testing environment.   I want to be able to run all the testing methods under different parameters that are set within their imports.   The way the testing methods in these classes are written the only alternative to changing the imports that I can see is duplicating dozens of class files and then hardcoding the altered imports.  Maybe there's another alternative.

Comment: There certainly is; you can use parameterized tests, passing in the relevant class as parameter, and the test code can use reflection to dynamically load the right peeler.